# Changing metadata for Ember.js apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ember.js, metadata, meta-tags

I have problems with linking my website (built with Ember.js) to Facebook (for each page - there's the same title, description, image etc - of course). I'm wondering if there is any solution to fight with this, without bringing that metadata (for each page) directly from the backend? I would like to change title, description, image etc for each page.

You can actually change title, description and other meta tags (by extending routes in Ember.js), but this is done only on client side and won't actually change the data so that Facebook for example can read the data and get the proper results.

Also, I cannot just put meta tags in  since that it's not valid.

So, is there any other solution to properly use "open graph" metadata inside Ember.js app?

Concrete example:

*http://www.skripinc.com/* -> this is the page about which I'm talking about. When I try to share it on Facebook, it will always pull the same Title, Description and image, which is set under metadata inside . I want to be able to have different metadata for each page, without bringing the data from the backend (with PHP or whatever).

Comment: Can you give a bit more of a concrete example of what you're trying to solve, I'm afraid I'm not quite grasping your problems (so I can figure out which is the correct response)

Comment: Sorry, it was kind of hard to explain for me. I've updated my question and added an example.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18929058/1806037

Comment: I've also had problems with setting up location: 'history' (didn't work for me), but will try to check it one more time. thanks.